# In XMLTEX what is XMT

Tags: xmltex

What is XML anybody can give quick guidance?

Need a difference between XSLT and XMT.
Which output will have more quality of the XML.

Comment: @Nico xmltex is a package from David, but it  is quite unclear if the question is about it.

Comment: @Mico `.xmt` is the extension given to the tex macro files in the xmltex system that I wrote in my youth..... So the question is on topic but I am not sure it is clear enough to answer

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - I’m Mico, not Nico.  I’ve withdrawn my close-because-off-topic vote; however, the query may deserve a close-because-unclear assessment.

Comment: @Mico I know, but my smartphone thought it knows better ;-)

Answer (score 4):

XML is a structured markup format, the details of which are off topic here but if you have files that look like

```
<something>
  <this>zzz</this>
  <value>2</value>
</something>
```

or

```
<p>This is <b>bold</b> text in a paragraph.</p>
```

Then it's xml.

XSLT is the standard XML processing language that can be used to convert one set of XML to another or to say LaTeX for typesetting.

xmltex is a system that I wrote at the start of the century to directly parse and typeset XML using TeX rather than explicitly convert it to tex using XSLT (or python or perl or whatever other programming language you prefer.)  The tex macro files (similar to latex `.sty` and `.cls` files) used by xmltex have extension `.xmt`.

xmltex has some interesting features and somewhat surprisingly perhaps a couple of publishing houses still use it to typeset documents that are in XML form, but I would definitely recommend that you use xslt and convert the xml to latex then produce typeset documents in the usual way if your requirement is to typeset XML documents.

There are hundreds of good XSLT tutorials on the web, and once you have converted your documents to latex it can be styled using standard latex techniques. If you use xmltex  then you are very much on your own with an unsupported system written by one person 20 years ago.